# How to insert composite objects into SQL table using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express

I'm learning Node and I used Spring Boot before where I used Hibernate ORM which enabled me to map objects like

```
{ 
 name:"John", 
 salary:50000, 
 address:{ 
  city: "Houston",
  state: "Texas"
 } 
}
```

into 2 separate tables for example Employee and Address and insert it. I wonder how it can be done in NodeJS and whats the best practice to map such data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the Hibernate ORM habit on NodeJS, you can use [bookshelfjs](https://bookshelfjs.org) or [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/). You have to make an insert process yourself regarding the json you shared.

```
var data = { 
 name:"John", 
 salary:50000, 
 address:{ 
  city: "Houston",
  state: "Texas"
 } 
};

connection.query('INSERT INTO Employee (NAME, SALARY) VALUES(?,?)', [data.name, data.salary], function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var lastInsertID = result.insertId;
    connection.query('INSERT INTO ADDRESS (CUSTOMER_ID, CITY, STATE) VALUES(?,?,?)', [lastInsertID, data.address.name, data.address.state], function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

    });
});
```